# multiple level categorical variable in weka

Tags: weka

I am a beginner in data mining. I am using weka. The data set has 109 variables of which many are nominal variables with many levels (1 to 8). My question is:

1.Should I convert the categorical variables (with upto 8 levels) to binary or use as it is?

Note: I'll be using logistic regression, random forest, naive bayes algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should work as is, but you may have different results if you pre-process the categorical data into binary.

Logistic Regression, Random Forests and Naive Bayes appears to use nominal values quite fine in Weka.  Some of these models may behave differently under the hood if you convert the attributes to binary.  I don't think the Logistic Regression would make much of a difference, but I'm not so sure about the Random Forest or Naive Bayes.